# Problem in disc partitioning while installing lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to install lubuntu 15.10 in my Pentium 4 pc, and I want to remove my previous operating system completely and use the space allotted to it for lubuntu and all the files and folder in other partition as intact (all files and folders) but I don't know how to do it. Which option should I choose for installing the OS I tried using **something else** but couldn't understand the procedure. So, please help thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: No my scenario is different i have only 80 Gb harddisk so even if i reduce the size of c: to install lubuntu(as suggested) then there will be no space for windows however i don't want to keep wimdows but what about those residual files of wimdows remain there(after creating the free space) . Is there no means i can format the c: and keep the d: as it is.

Comment: +1 for sending Windows into oblivion. :) I have answered you below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu taking up the whole disk, the procedure is even easier.

Install from CD-ROM or USB drive as usual, then when the installer ask about partitioning select the option "Use the whole disk". The installer will warn you that it has detected an existing OS; just ignore the warning and go ahead. Your Windows partition will be nuked and your computer will be happily running Ubuntu.

I am not sure whether this type of partitioning leaves in its place  the Windows recovery partition; but if yes, you can safely leave it there -- it's just a couple of Gb in size.

Comment: But what about the existing files in the other drive like photos,videos and docs etc won't they all get deleted by this procedure thanks@dr0

Comment: Are your pics and docs in the same partition as Windows or in a different partition? If it's the former, copy it to a USB thumb drive and do as suggested above. If it's the latter, use Guided Partitioning and exclude the data partition from the install (but I'd do a backup of your files on a USB drive anyway, just in case).

Comment: So anyways i have to use guided partition, ok then should or shouldn't i format the c: to create the free space??

Comment: If your data files *are not* in C:, yes.